# Getting generic permissions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I created some roles in SQL Server using SSMS, and I have not found any code to search the system tables for generic permissions, so I can write a script to generate t-sql to create it.  For example, if I create a stored stored procedure and grant permissions to it:

```
grant execute on sp_blah to testrole
```

However, if I create a generic permission like

```
grant execute to testrole
```

I have had not luck hunting down where to find those permissions so I can script them out, and they don't display in SSMS.  How do I find generic permissions so I can generate a transact sql script?

Answer (score 1):

Those are database permissions.

```
select user_name(grantee_principal_id) grantee, 
       class_desc, 
       permission_name, 
       state_desc 
from sys.database_permissions
where class_desc = 'DATABASE'
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If it answers the question, @928-5.0 , you should mark it as the solution, so that future users know the answer was helpful.